# Citing caret R package in APA style

Tags: r, citations

I used `caret` package to do neural network analysis and need to cite the package in APA style. But, `citation("caret") doesn't look like a typical APA style. Can anyone make it to the APA 6th style? Thanks.

```
To cite package ‘caret’ in publications use:

  Max Kuhn. Contributions from Jed Wing, Steve Weston, Andre Williams,
  Chris Keefer, Allan Engelhardt, Tony Cooper, Zachary Mayer, Brenton
  Kenkel, the R Core Team, Michael Benesty, Reynald Lescarbeau, Andrew
  Ziem, Luca Scrucca, Yuan Tang and Can Candan. (2016). caret:
  Classification and Regression Training. R package version 6.0-71.
  https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=caret
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kuhn, M. (2008). Caret package. Journal of Statistical Software, 28(5)

Answer (score 4):

Here is the citation format in APA:

```
Kuhn, M. (2008). Building Predictive Models in R Using the caret Package. Journal of Statistical Software, 28(5), 1 - 26. doi:http://dx.doi.org/10.18637/jss.v028.i05
```

The citation format in BibTex (in latex):

```
@article{JSSv028i05,
   author = {Max Kuhn},
   title = {Building Predictive Models in R Using the caret Package},
   journal = {Journal of Statistical Software, Articles},
   volume = {28},
   number = {5},
   year = {2008},
   keywords = {},
   abstract = {The caret package, short for classification and regression training, contains numerous tools for developing predictive models using the rich set of models available in R. The package focuses on simplifying model training and tuning across a wide variety of modeling techniques. It also includes methods for pre-processing training data, calculating variable importance, and model visualizations. An example from computational chemistry is used to illustrate the functionality on a real data set and to benchmark the benefits of parallel processing with several types of models.},
   issn = {1548-7660},
   pages = {1--26},
   doi = {10.18637/jss.v028.i05},
   url = {https://www.jstatsoft.org/v028/i05}
}
```

Please refer to the following website for other formats:

https://www.jstatsoft.org/rt/captureCite/v028i05/0/ApaCitationPlugin